# Post multiple images into web server

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, ios7, nsurlconnection

The code make me very happy to Post image into Web server. its working smart for single image. The code what i've to used to Post a single image is

```
NSLog(@"%@",requestString);

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/InsertFacialImage?%@",requestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Then i failed to jump over the hurdle, Failed to Post 2 images with different services.The truth behind my failure is after uploading of the 1st image, server generate response then i've attach the response to second service. i did it properly but failed because i made the connection run 2 times for 2 images.but Web services team asking me that run it in a single connection.The code which i is used, which i need to modify is

***Posting 1st image***

```
 NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/InsertObjectImage?%@",requestString];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage1, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData;
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);

NSURLConnection *connReq = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connReq) {

    NSLog(@"Connection Sucessful");
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}


else {

    NSLog(@"failed");

}

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Status code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
```

***Generating Response***

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
[self.receivedData appendData:data];
```

}

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"%@" , error);
```

}

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSError *e;



jsonDict1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

compareId = [jsonDict1 valueForKey:@"ImageId"];
```

NSLog(@"JSONN%@" , jsonDict1);

```
compareId = [results.firstObject objectForKey:@"ImageId"];


NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.compareId forKey:@"Sendy"];
[defaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"compareId:%@",compareId);


results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];



}
```

}

after this step is response is generating good and i can pass it to the second string. so no  problem with the server response.

***Post 2nd Image ***

```
NSString *url1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/UpdateObjectImage?%@",requestString1];

NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request1 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1]];
[request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request1 setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage2, 0.2f);
[request1 addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body1 = [NSMutableData data];
[body1 appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request1 setHTTPBody:body1];

NSData *returnData;
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);


NSURLConnection *connReq = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];

if (connReq) {

    NSLog(@"Connection Sucessful");
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}

else {

    NSLog(@"failed");

}

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Status code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
```

Comment: y u serialize the data in 3 times from server, what the reason of it

Comment: where i serilased the 3 times...

Comment: ya got it . no need to serialize it 3 times. check my edit @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: jsonDict1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

compareId =[jsonDict1 valueForKey:@"ImageId"];

results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

compareId = [results.firstObject objectForKey:@"ImageId"];


NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.compareId forKey:@"Sendy"];
[defaults synchronize];

Comment: what the meaning of it, k leave it is not a constrain, k what the problem u meet

Comment: tried to post 2 images into webserver, but not working